# Docker containers handling more load

Tags: docker

I have a question regarding Docker containers.
Increasing number of containers of an application in a same Virtual Machine, will mean it will handle more load (approx -> factor of the number of containers) ?

Assuming we don't assign the resources to the containers explicitly. And We are running the reverse proxy (or a load-balancer) in a same machine which will forward the requests (to containers) in a round-robin mechanism. If the current throughput is 1000 tps of one container, does that mean it will be ~3000 tps with 3 containers?

Has anyone done the performance bench marking? can anyone share the link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q:** Increasing number of containers of an application in a same Virtual Machine, will mean it will handle more load?

**A:** It depends on where your current bottleneck is.

If your virtual machine is currently running at 100% CPU workload, then throwing more containers will obviously not increase your throughput. It might instead degrade your `tps` as additional CPU resources will need to be allocated to the new process of your new container instance.

Assuming your VM is running at low workload at the moment, RAM and disk IO isn't an issue. Throwing more processes may still not mean better performance as the problem can sometimes be at a piece of inefficient code. E.g. A thread waiting on an asynchronous call's response or something causing the entire process to be locked up, or a thread is waiting for a lock before it could proceed further while the other thread is hogging on to the lock for a long period of time. Etc...

Your application's architecture and existing code bottleneck can play a huge role on impacting the overall performance as well.

**Q:** Will throughput be increased approximately based on the factor of the number of containers?

Unlikely. If 1 container can do 1k `tps` it doesn't always equate to `n * 1k` where `n` is the number of containers. This is because as mentioned before there are just too many variables to consider.

The overall performance may also depends on what load balancer you are using and how it is configured.

In general, it is still worth throwing more containers with a load balancer orchestrating the application's incoming request. If you are not liking the performance increase then I would recommend doing a code profiling and probably also investigate on the system's load and come out with theories why this is happening. Then systematically fix the bottleneck 1 by 1 until you are happy with the performance.

Unlocking a bottleneck will always open up another new bottleneck.

Comment: @user1819071 let me know if this is helpful to you or not, happy to discuss further

Comment: Thanks a lot it was very informative. We are doing more analysis and probably will get back to you again.

Comment: @SamuelToh
Why wouldn't you just have one container for a given workload then?

It's not clear to me why you would ever need more than one, given that more containers wont be able to handle more load.

Comment: @ignaciofuentes Assuming you have a `nodejs` application that is badly coded e.g. writing to a file using the non-async api. Upon receiving a http request with huge content to write to that file through the synchronise way means that the `javascript` applicaiton is going to get blocked. Throwing another container into the ecosystem means that, if another http request comes through, even though container A is process blocked, Container B can still service that request. Hope this helps.